# Python: Choose function based on condition in a for loop?

Tags: python, function

Sorry if the title is a little vague. I'll explain everything in greater detail here. So let's say I have this code:

```
def function1(k):
    return k * 2


def function2(k):
    return k ** 2


func = 'Square'

for i in range(1, 10):
    if func == 'Multiply':
        function1(i)
    elif func == 'Square':
        function2(i)
```

How can I modify the code above so that the if statement can go outside the loop? It seems unnecessary to check in every iteration the value of `func` since it's not going to change inside. the loop. What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
def function1(k):
    return k * 2


def function2(k):
    return k ** 2


func = 'Square'

if func == 'Multiply':
     f = function1()
elif func == 'Square':
     f = function2()

for i in range(1, 10):
    f(i)
```

Let me know if something isn't clear enough or if what I'm asking isn't possible.

Comment: you're very close; just assign as `f = function1` (this adds the _name_ `f` to the reference, so both refer to the same function) and continue to `f(i)`, which then _calls_ it

Comment: Note: To square a number in Python, you need to use `x**2`, not `x^2`.  The latter is a bitwise XOR.

Comment: @ti7 Thank you so much! It was driving me crazy hahaha

Comment: @0x5453 Corrected. Matlab residuals :)

Answer (score 5):

Store the function in a `dict`, then you can skip the `if` statements.

```
def function1(k):
    return k * 2

def function2(k):
    return k ** 2

d = {"Multiply": function1, "Square": function2}

func = "Square"
f = d[func]
f(3)
# 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```py
funcs = {'Multiply':function1, 'Square':function2}
theFunc = funcs[func]
for i in range(1, 10):
    x = theFunc(i)
    print(x)
```

One note in passing: the `^` operator is not taking the square of the argument, but rather performing bitwise xor on it.